# SASS installation issues with Grunt

Tags: javascript, ruby, sass, gruntjs, rubygems

I'm trying to run a Grunt SASS task with Cygwin on windows. I keep getting this error:

```
Shreyansh@Shrey-PC ~/Projects/Resview
$ grunt
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

So I simply searched online and tried doing the following to fix my issue:

```
Shreyansh@Shrey-PC ~/Projects/Resview
$ gem install sass
Successfully installed sass-3.4.22
Parsing documentation for sass-3.4.22
Done installing documentation for sass after 6 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Unfortunately this gave me the same message, I then put this in my PATH variable following the instructions [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) and installed it globally through using the Command prompt. This still however gave me the same message.

Am I missing anything to get SASS to work? I think I followed all the steps necessary and can't seem to figure out what the problem could be.

EDIT: I can confirm that ruby is already installed

Comment: dont forget ruby!

Comment: I've installed ruby as well

Comment: Would using [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) be an option for you?

Comment: I've tried grunt-sass but there isnt a repository for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SASS on your machine

```
gem install sass
```

Comment: Yup, as said in the question I've already added Ruby in my PATH

Comment: try grunt-libsass instead!